# .htaccess within folder, making the folder itself disapear

Tags: .htaccess

i'm new, and wanna try MVC pattern which is need to using .htaccess rule.
I have .htaccess file within both folder that listing below.
[image: htaccess]
this is the rule that i used to `.htaccess` file in `app/` folder:

```
Options -Indexes
```

and this is the rule that i used to `.htaccess` file in `public/` folder:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in the `app/` folder the htaccess file works where its folder access is forbidden, but not for the `public/` folder since the `public/` folder is not listed.

can someone tell me why this happended ? and how to solve this?

hope you are not confused with my explantion and sorry for my bad english
thank you before

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. 1. please add some request URLs to the question and 2. explain _exactly_ what happens and why that is wrong in your eyes. Note: do not add information in comments here, but to the question itself. There is an `edit` link below it. _Use it_ ...

Comment: Please do not insert a solution in the question itself: instead, please undelete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Solved, i forgot to enable mod rewrite,
so i just run this command**

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```